# Dynamically turn off Ajax Control Toolkit Autocomplete Extender

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I'm trying to dynamically enable/disable an Autocomplete extender control from the Ajax Control Toolkit based on a choice a user makes in a dropdown list.

My ASP.NET 4.0 Webforms app has a dropdown list, and depending on which country is selected from it, the zipcode autoextender should be enabled or disabled.

My markup:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCountries">
    <Items>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Switzerland" Value="CH" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Germany" Value="D" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Italy" Value="I" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="France" Value="F" />
    </Items>
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />

<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbxZipcode" />

<asp:AutoCompleteExtender 
     runat="server" ID="acZipcode" BehaviorID="ZipcodeBehavior" 
     ServiceMethod="GetZipCode"
     TargetControlID="tbxZipCode" MinimumPrefixLength="1" CompletionInterval="15" 
     OnClientItemSelected="PopulateTextboxes" CompletionSetCount="25" />
```

With this setup, the autocomplete extender kicks in and displays valid Swiss zipcodes - life is good :-)

**HOWEVER**: if the user selects another country, I want to **stop** this autocomplete extender - I don't have the other zipcodes in my database to display, and displaying Swiss zipcodes for France doesn't make sense.

So I tried something like this to grab the `change` event on the drop down list

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#<%= ddlCountries.ClientID %>').change(function () {
      var chosenCountry = $(this).val();

      var behavior = $('#ZipcodeBehavior');

      if (chosenCountry == "CH") {
         behavior.disabled = '';
      } else {
         behavior.disabled = 'disabled';
      }
   });
});
```

I can get the `ZipcodeBehavior` just fine - but once I have it - nothing seems to work anymore...

How do I dynamically disable the Ajax Control Toolkit's AutocompleteExtender?

In markup, statically, I do it using

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender Enabled="False" .... />
```

and then nothing at all gets rendered into my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First at all, you can't get MicrosoftAjax client object by jQuery selector. So this syntax `var behavior = $('#ZipcodeBehavior');` doesn't make sense. Use `$find("BehaviorID")` instead.

To add disabling capability to AutoCompleteExtender add reference on this script to `ScriptManager` control:

```
Sys.Extended.UI.AutoCompleteBehavior.prototype.set_enabled = function (value) {
    try {
        $removeHandler(this.get_element(), "keydown", this._keyDownHandler);
    } catch (error) {} //just escape error if handler already removed
    this._timer.set_enabled( !! value);
    if (value) {
        this._keyDownHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, this._onKeyDown);
    } else {
        this._keyDownHandler = Function.createDelegate(this, function () {});
    }
    $addHandler(this.get_element(), "keydown", this._keyDownHandler);
};
```

After that you may to disabled/enable extender with this code:

```
$('#<%= ddlCountries.ClientID %>').change(function () {
    var chosenCountry = $(this).val();
    $find("ZipcodeBehavior").set_enabled(chosenCountry == "CH");
});
```

BTW, with `Enabled="false"` property specified in markup I'm afraid you shouldn't enable extender on client.

Comment: +1 Javascript really does border on Black Magic and Voodoo.... :-) I have **no clue** what exactly you're doing here - but it works like a charm! Thanks!